# Question about propagation of diseases

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x=\dfrac{500}{499 \mathsf e^{-500kt}+1}$$

I was looking up for formulas for propagation of diseases and found an example that used this formula. What's the formula's name? Are there any other formulas?

Answer (score 4):

This is the well-known [Logistic model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function).